# Car / Vehicle automatic wheel rotation

Tags: animation

I am making a vehicle with working wheels and I've search so many times and found solutions that all work until I turn the wheel (along the Z axis).

Is there a way of making wheels that automaticly rotate when moved in the *local Y axis*?

**I need it to work when moved along a path.**

Thanks,

The Blender Kid

Comment: Welcome to BSE, what have you tried so far? Do you have a blend?  An image?  In it's current form this question is pretty broad.

Comment: @batFINGER
Basically I have a fire truck I need to move along a path with automatically rotating wheels. Ideally I would like to be able to turn the wheels. 
The truck will follow the path out of a building/fire station and turn to the right and then follow a straight path from there before coming to a stop - so just a few seconds of animation.

I've tried these two tutorials:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oozxxdVp4f4
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IKJzyFF-Ro

And an Animation Nodes setup that I created myself.

Thank you
The Blender Kid